# How can I test a SAP Business One Add-On using Browser Access Mode?

Tags: c#, sapb1

I have developed an add-on using Visual Studio 2013 and I'm running it on SAP Business One Client, how can I open it on a browser using Browser Access Mode.

Comment: you are using HANA?

Answer (score 0):

Although a little late to the party, here's what you need to do to run the add-on in the Browser

In the SBO-Common Database run the following query:

```
UPDATE SARI SET ClientType = 'A' WHERE EName = 'NameOfAdd-On.exe'
```

Now your add-on will be able to run in Browser Access Mode.

Cheers